# WIX: Reference URL of html files saved in public folder for my html iframe

Tags: iframe, velo

Is there a way to do this?  I know that I could just put the html directly into the iframe, but I don't like this option because if I have copies of that iframe in many pages and I need to make a change to the code, I want to be able to make that change in one place and have the changes reflected everywhere rather than going into each and every iframe and making the change.

When adding an iframe in a wix site, one can either copy/paste the code into the iframe's code section, or one can provide a URL in the iframe's website address section.  Is it possible to put the URL of one of my html files that are located in the public section?  If so, what does the URL look like?